# How to use service response result within other function in Angular 5

Tags: angular

i have call a service

```
 constructor(private checkout: CheckoutService,private routers: Router) { }

 this.checkout.getCustomerOrderId(userid).subscribe(result=>{ result });
```

******  getCustomerOrderId() function used in service file ******

```
 getCustomerOrderId(param){
            return this.http.get(this.ROOT+'getcustomerorderid'+param).map(
              (response: Response) => {
                return response.json();
              });
            }
```

******  MyOtherFunction() function used in ts file ******

```
MyOtherFunction(){

    Here i want to use result data   (service response result)

}
```

then get back the response properly.
so how i can use this Response result within another function in ts file.
Thanks

Comment: This example is unclear, are we talking about the subscription or the getCustomerOrderID? And you want to store the result for later use or process it immediately when it comes in?

Comment: Thanks @Florian for response

this is just a function name getCustomerOrderId()

Comment: declare a variable in your class and in the service subscription evaluate that variable with the response: `this.variableForLaterUse = result` and you can use this variable in `MyOtherFunction()` method.

Comment: Thanks @standby954
i'm able to use the value of this.variableForLaterUse in .html page but not able to use within MyOtherFunction() 

variableForLaterUse:any

Comment: Where is your `MyOtherFunction()` located? In Service or  in Component?

Comment: @SonuBamniya

I think Its more clear  to understand now

Answer (score 0):

Make another variable and store the data in it

Now with this method it depends on when you actually call your MyOtherFunction(), if you are calling it at the component start itself, you can't be sure whether you have data in your other variable as it's an async. Whereas if you have called this function in an event or something, then you can probably be sure that your other another variable has data.

You can use this another variable irrespectively in your html.
But if the you are calling MyOtherfunction at start then you should either have an event emitter or call that function inside the response call after assigning your another variable the result

Something like this

```
this.anotherVariable: any;

getCustomerOrderId(param){
            return this.http.get(this.ROOT+'getcustomerorderid'+param).map(
              (response: Response) => {
                this.anotherVariable = result
                this.MyOtherFunction()
                return response.json();
              });
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure that the service runs before you use the variable in MyOtherFunction. Double check that for instance with console.log

```
This.laterUse:any

this.checkout.getCustomerOrderId(userid).subscribe(result=>{ this.laterUse =  result });

getCustomerOrderId(param){
            return this.http.get(this.ROOT+'getcustomerorderid'+param).map(
              (response: Response) => {
                return response.json();
              });
            }

MyOtherFunction(){

    console.log(this.laterUse) 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood, you want to use *getCustomerOrderID* in your *myOtherFunction*. So, if you subscribes to *getCustomerOrderID* in *myOtherFunction* you will handle this response in your ts file.
Here is the code:

```
MyOtherFunction(userid){
    this.checkout.getCustomerOrderId(userid).subscribe(
       result => { 
           // Here you can use the result data
       },
       error => {
           console.log(error);
       }
   );
}
```

> WITH GLOBAL PROPERTY, not recommended.

```
private customerOrderID;

constructor(private checkout: CheckoutService,private routers: Router) { }

initializeCustomerId(userid){
   this.checkout.getCustomerOrderId(userid).subscribe(
      result => {
         this.customerOrderID = result;
      },
      error => {
         console.log(error);
      }
   );
}

MyOtherFunction(){
   // If you wants to initialize this customerOrderID
   initializeCustomerId(userid);
   // If you initialized customerOrderID you will have the result here
   this.customerOrderId;
}
```

Now you will choose the way to initialize this customerID, well in the constructor or in the function you will to use.

Comment: if i want to use result data more then one function then we need to call getCustomerOrderId service again and again ?

Comment: Not, if you wants to have a global property which have the customer.order.id, you should do something like this. But the better way to control your system is calling getCustomerOrderId at the same time that you need your result. If you do this you will cover problems about outdated data.

Comment: Thanks @JoseJimRin